# Unhandled Promise Rejection with a .catch()

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, ecmascript-6, promise

I'm having trouble debugging my first Javascript tool which uses promises. I feel like I am using the .catch() method correctly, as it matches up with other StackOverflow answers to similar questions that have been asked, however I'd still receiving an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning for uncaught promises.

My program fetches a list of objects from an S3 and then logs them to console.

Here is the promise chain

```
s3Helper.setCredentials(program.profile)
  .then(s3Helper.findObjects([], null))
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => utl.error(err));
```

And here are the two promises

```
function findObjects (keyArray, token) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var S3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
    var params = {
      Bucket: program.bucket,
      Prefix: program.prefix,
      Delimiter: program.recursive ? '' : '/',
      ContinuationToken: token
    };

    S3.listObjectsV2(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
}

function setCredentials (profile) {
  // Sets AWS credentials, and rejects if the profile is not found
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: profile});
    AWS.config.credentials.refresh((err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else if (AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId) {
        resolve();
      } else if (AWS.config.credentials.roleArn) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        var error = {
          message: `Given profile '${program.profile}' does not exist`
        };
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Sorry if my style or code is bad, I'm still getting used to Javascript!

Comment: Where is the error happening?

Comment: Unless `s3Helper.findObjects([], null)` returns a function, that's not going to work. You probably meant to say `.then(() => s3Helper.findObjects([], null))`. But in your catch statement, you also probably meant `util.error()` instead of `utl.error()`. So your `catch()` is generating another error that isn't handled by another `catch()` chain.

Comment: @FrankerZ [`util.error()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_error_strings) is just a deprecated call equivalent to `console.error()`.

Comment: utl is a seperate library I'm using but thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: `.then(fn)`, just like `setTimeout(fn,d)`, needs a function to call when it's done its thing. You instead called the function, thus executing it immediately, not waiting for the promise to resolve.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts

Comment: Thanks @KevinB !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your promise chain should look like this:

```
s3Helper.setCredentials(program.profile)
  .then(() => s3Helper.findObjects([], null))
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => util.error(err));
```

Note the function: () => ... on the second line

Then `.then()` method takes a function as it's argument. So you must pass it a function.

Therefore, `.then(s3Helper.findObjects([], null))` would only work if `s3Helper.findObjects([], null)` returns a function. But based on you definition of `s3Helper.findObjects([], null)`, it doesn't. So you need to update your `.then()` method to `.then(() => s3Helper.findObjects([], null))`.

Comment: Thanks! Whats the difference between what I was doing and this method? I was of the impression you could just call a function if you weren't returning any parameters without the parenthesis and the fat arrow

Comment: Then `.then()` method takes a function as it's argument. So you must pass it a function.  Look at my updated answer above.